# Why use hidden field to detect form submission?

Tags: php, forms

I've been reading PHP form handling tutorials, and they suggest using a hidden field in the form so PHP can use something like `IF ($_POST['hidden_field'] == whatever` to detect whether the form was submitted or only displayed.

But after getting `XDebug` working with Notepad++ and stepping through the code and observing the variables, it's not clear to me why we can't just go `IF ($_POST['submit_button'] == 'Ok')` and do away with the hidden field entirely.

After all, there doesn't seem to be a time when the hidden field is set without the other form fields being set too (even if they're empty). The first time through, when the form is being displayed and before it has been submitted, the `$_POST` variable already exists, but it is empty. I suppose we could also use `IF (!empty($_POST))` to see if the form has been submitted?

Is there a special case I'm missing where the hidden field is necessary to detect form submission?

EDIT: Ok, the special case I was missing and that requires the hidden field appears to be this. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?562749-PHP-Checking-if-a-form-has-been-submitted-the-correct-way It seems that if you hit Enter to submit the form, the $_POST variable will not include the value of the submit button. Chrome doesn't seem to behave that way but maybe other browsers do.

Comment: To be fairly honest with you none of those are correct. The correct way would be to verify all the fields you require for your application to work which makes the hidden or submit button not needed in the form of hey this is being submitted, as long as the required fields are filled and validated you should then accept the post **and you should never trust on user input you should always validate against what the field must be.** To put it simple you don't need a field to know a form is being posted there are other ways you can detect that besides a button or hidden field.

Comment: Yes, all fields should be validated, but before you start validating fields, shouldn't you first determine if the form has been submitted? Otherwise, your script will think the fields weren't filled and will display the form for the first time already with error messages.

Comment: like I have mentioned you don't need to rely on fields/button to know its being submitted.

Comment: @Prix Thanks, but look, I'm a noob. I'm not an engineer at Facebook. Can you tell me, without riddles, how do you know the user submitted the form, either by clicking a button or hitting Enter? That's all I really hope to learn from this question, not how to validate fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have the right idea.

I wouldn't recommend doing this, however - sounds like whoever wrote the tutorial is a bit of a newbie. ;)  If you're using POSTs for your forms already, I'd stick with the more traditional (and simpler) method of detecting whether the form was submitted or if someone is just viewing the page by means of the HTTP method ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], as "GET" or "POST" in PHP).

Comment: Just to be clear, Prix has the right idea - "never trust user input to be valid ... always validate against what the field must be."  In general, you shouldn't think that viewing-submitting are two states of a state machine, either - so your program (PHP script) should perform correctly even if you get a form submission without a corresponding page view.  If, however, your requirements are such that it must be a state machine, you'll need to consider programming your script with a field that will be used to guarantee transitions in the state machine (a good use of hidden fields)

Comment: I get the part about not trusting input to be valid, but I'm not sure about not thinking of it as viewing/submitting.

Under the coding style (for want of a better term) where you have your PHP code first and then the form, one of the first things the PHP script needs to ask itself is, "Am I processing the form this time around or just displaying it?"

Comment: That's fine, but what I'm saying is that, checking REQUEST_METHOD is only valid if you're not setting up a state machine where viewing of the page is required for submission of the form.  Consider it this way - would it be acceptable for me to fill out the form and submit it to you without ever seeing the page?  In general, the answer is "yes;" but sometimes, you'll want to do a little more than that, such as protecting privileged accesses against CSRF.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm lost. I'm sure it's me and not you. You're just miles ahead of the learning curve. Where I'm at, you can't submit the form without first seeing the page. I can't imagine how someone could submit a form without first looking at it. Anyway, as my edit to my original question shows, I think I found why hidden fields are used to detect if a form was submitted, but thanks for the food for thought. I'll get there. :)

Comment: If you want a way to imagine it, look at https://fiddler2.com/.  One can construct an HTTP POST request to your script, possibly populated with values that might be considered valid.  Would any of your requirements be broken if someone crafted arbitrary POST requests to your script?  If so, you may need to implement proper CSRF protection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37805/discussion-between-user314104-and-robertsf)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a special case I'm missing where the hidden field is
>   necessary to detect form submission?

To detect the form submission you don't need a hidden field in the form but some times it's used as a spam protection.  For example, if you put a hidden field in your form, like

```
<input type="text" name="humans" id="humans" class="humans" />
```

You may use a css class to hide the filed like

```
.humans { display: none; }
```

and when you check the form submission, you may also check if the field is empty or not, like

```
if(!empty($_POST['humans'])) {
// it's spam
}
else {
// it's human
}
```

Because, `bots/spammers` (using automated script) can submit the form and basically the `script` tries to fill up all the fields and doesn't know about the hidden field that you have put to catch it and this way you may determine whether it's submitted by a human or bot. You may [read this article](http://doteduguru.com/id3038-are-you-human-is-captcha-needed-some-alternatives.html) for more information and better understanding of spam blocking..

Comment: That was always my understanding of this practice. How smart are bots, though?

Comment: `How smart are bots, though?` Depends, how smart the programmer is who writes the script, after a period of time every trick become known to programmers and as well as bots too, so there is always need for new trick.

Comment: Ok, I had heard of using hidden fields against spam, but didn't know the details, so thanks for that.

Comment: But why would the humans field be empty?  Just because it's hidden via CSS doesn't mean that it is omitted from the form -- which is what a typical bot would use.

Answer (score 1):

Why implement a [hidden] field to check if the form is submitted when you must have other fields to check by if you have a form in the first place.
Other than checking if submitted, the hidden field is redundant, and so just pointless extra code.

If you have multiple forms on a page, name the submit button, if only one, just check if `$_POST` `isset()`, then go about validating data, etc etc

You can use `!empty($_POST)` instead, but I try to avoid this (depending on scenario) as I like to tell the user they did not enter anything, otherwise user clicks submit and it just hows them the blank form again.

Sure they would likely know they're messing around, but perhaps they thought they typed something, for numerous potential reasons.
Always good to keep users appraised, especially of any potential mistakes on their part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in using a hidden field just to check that the form has been submitted.

But let's say you want to dynamically post a value that there is no reason to show in the form.
For example you have an array `$user` that holds all the data of a user. The user submits the form, and you pass as a hidden field `$user['id']` to work with their id after the submission.

Or you find their language through IP or whatever and pass it as a hidden field to show a message in their language.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't do this myself, I would say that it can be useful to undermine `curl` or other methods of accessing the site outside of a regular browser - of course the hidden field has to differ with every request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple use of hidden field to validate a submit

- as you mentioned, differentiating between form view and submission.
- as @kingkero mentioned, a way to block form auto submissions by robots.

and in case of editing an existing record

- a primary key is required to locate original record, and it should be hidden so user can't change it
- you can save old data somewhere in server side before sending to browser and then send a reference key to that data as hidden field, later it can be used to compare old and new data to determine what has been changed.
- in multi-user system, if more then one user select to edit and save a specific record at the same time then there is chance that they can overwrite each-other!! to prevent this situation a hidden field can be used to determine and notify user if selected record has been changed during form load and submit period.